# Why Android is storing dynamic views in RAM?

Tags: android, memory-management, ram

Question may seem weird but I ran in an issue with Android app. I am creating views for my Android app dynamically using layout inflater and the view contains images. Most images are less than 800kb. So when I open the app, it starts using tons of RAM and when I switch to another activity, it adds more ram which contains images too. When I exit the activity and come back to the first activity it is not cleaning the RAM. I cannot add my actual code here because of the company policy but here is the snippet of what I am doing,

I have two activities `HomeActivity` and `DisplayActivity`. In home activity I have empty scrollview. I am making db query an pulling information. Using layout inflater,

```
for (DataModel d : dm) {
JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject(d.getData());


View headerCard = LayoutInflater.from(HomeActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.head_card, null);

ImageView cardHeadImage = (ImageView) headerCard.findViewById(R.id.head_card_header_image);
TextView cardNote = (TextView) headerCard.findViewById(R.id.head_card_note);

String imageLink = dataJson.getJSONObject("data").getString("article_image");

String note = dataJson.getJSONObject("data").getString("article_title");

imageLoader.displayImage(h.getMediaURL() + imageLink, cardHeadImage);
cardNote.setText(note);


scrollViewChild.addView(headerCard);
}
```

So when I don't add images, it is using less RAM. I have cached images. So my question is that is there anything possible to clear RAM after view is generated and placed in display? I can provide more information if needed. But basically this is how my both activities are running.

The `imageLoader` works in three steps. 1) Check for cached image. 2) If image is not cached than download image and cache it. 3) Display image in imageview. 2nd step will be skipped most time as images are mostly available from cache.

Thanks. :D

Comment: You can do [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html) to reduce RAM usage.

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak, I have tried that. It doesn't make lot difference in RAM and it is displaying unclear images.